# What is isoepiphany in math?

Tags: geometry, terminology, geometric-measure-theory

Archimedes studied isoepiphany, later handled by an arabic scholar al Haytham
but I can't find a defintion?

Comment: I see only one person using that phrase on a quick Google search. It may be a very nonstandard term.

Comment: Every mention of the word I can find online is by the same person, Athanase Papadopoulos. Maybe it's an alternate spelling of a more common term? (Maybe relevant: the Greek word for "surface" is "επιφάνεια," so this might just be Papadopoulos' term for the surface area analogues of isoperimetric problems.)

Answer (score 2):

Note "isoperimetry" and "isoepiphany" are often listed together.

Classically, the isoperimetric theorem is:  among plane figures with given perimeter, the figure of maximum area is the circle.  The corresponding isoepiphanic theorem is: among solid bodies with given surface area, the body of maximum volume is the sphere.

Classical Greek geometers formulated these but did not prove them.

> In 1882 the first satisfactory proofs of the classical isoperimetric and isoepiphanic problems were published, by L. Edlinand and H. A. Schwartz, respectively

quoted from:
Danilova, N. Ī., "The development of the traditional methods of isoperimetric theory".(Russian) *Sketches on the history of mathematical physics* (Russian), 41–47, vol. 184 (1985)